# Tokenizing unsplit workds using NLTK/Python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk

I have unsplit words such as `PageMetadataServiceConsumer`, `PowerSellerUpdateConsumerApplication`, `MetaDataDomain` etc. These are words that don't have any punctuation or verbs. But when we look at the word, we know what they are made up of.

Is there a way to split `PowerSellerUpdateConsumerApplication` into `Power`,`Seller`, `Update`,`Consumer`, `Application` using **nltk**?

Comment: did the solution work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following approach :

The idea is to append a splitter string (in the following string it is ###) to the left of Uppercase character(s) ... If you somehow think that ### may appear as a string then you may use anything like ~!@*@&$@#! or whatever you think is 100% safe to not appear in the string at all.

[Run Here](https://ideone.com/B4fM0g)

```
import re

regex = r"([A-Z]+)"
test_str = "agePowerSellerUpdateConsumerApplicationMetaDataDomainageMetadataServiceConsumerBBc"
subst = "###\\1"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
  print(re.split("###", result))
```

Comment: try it on `agePowerSellerUpd###ateConsumer` or even `agePowerSellerUpdate###Consumer`

Comment: what you trying to put up can be solved by something which can never occur or designated as a word or anything for example ~!!@*@!bulbus~!!@*@!! can be used instead of ### ... I thought it was easily understandable

Comment: All am trying to say is you can split using first re itself, instead of using a second re!

Comment: No, with my regex had I used split on the first go then the uppercase characters would disappear or if I put it as capture group then the upper case character would come as different  word individually.

Comment: what i meant was find instead of split.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s='PageMetadataServiceConsumer, PowerSellerUpdateConsumerApplication, MetaDataDomain'
reg=r'[A-Z](?![a-z]*\b)[a-z]+'
a=re.sub(reg,'\g<0> ',s)
print(a)
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
Page Metadata Service Consumer, Power Seller Update Consumer Application, Meta Data Domain
```

---

**Explanation**

```
[A-Z]        #First char with capital letter
(?!          #START Negative Look ahead: Do not match if the first char is followed by this
[a-z]*\b    #do not match if it ends with a word boundary \b(last part)
)            #END Negative Look ahead
[a-z]+      #Select all the remaining lower case chars.


a=re.sub(reg,'\g<0> ',s) #Replace the matches with match \g<0> by appending a space to it.
```

Working regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kly2dz/1).
Working python example [here](https://repl.it/MHgt/0).

---

If you just want the words then use the below:-

```
reg=r'[A-Z]+[a-z]+'
for a in re.findall(reg,s):
  print(a)
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
Page
Metadata
Service
Consumer
Power
Seller
Update
Consumer
Application
Meta
Data
Domain
```

Comment: Your regex makes BBcBlablabla into B, Bc Blablabla

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman No it doesn't, can you re-try? my link might have an older version.

Comment: Using lookahead makes it slow when comparing with my answer... you can benchmark yourself

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman that one I've to give your answer! I up-voted yours

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman although according to OP, he needed only words, so my second part of the answer still holds faster than yours ;-)

Comment: Watchout : https://repl.it/MHgt/1 I still get separate words for more than one Captial together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155986/discussion-between-bulbus-and-rizwan-m-tuman).